# how to view Active Directory Computer in my local network

Tags: domain

this is waqar from Pakistan. i m new in domain active Directory. i installed domain network in 5 computers.

Server :-   windows Server 2003
client :-   Windows Xp and windows vista

how can i find server and other computers to a xp client?

Regards

Waqar Mehmood

Answer (score 0):

If your client computers have been joined to the domain, then the server resources should automatically show up in the network neighborhood. If they don't show up, or they show up in a separate entity, then you should put the workstation computers into the domain.

Comment: That's not strictly true. NetBIOS over TCP needs to be enabled to facilitate the population of Network Neighborhood or My Network Places.